# Replacement for the "<" operator

Tags: windows, cmd

In the Windows cmd, I am using the < operator to read the command input from a file.

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite < command.txt
```

sqlite3 is an application and the content of command.txt is this:

```
.backup '..\database_backup\2012-11-30-16-16-28.bak'
```

Everytime, I generate a new command.txt file (because I should change the .bak file name) and then I use the < operator to feed it to the sqlite3.exe. Is there any way that I can circumvent the command.txt generation and feed all input parameters directly to the sqlite3.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo ".backup '..\database_backup\2012-11-30-16-16-28.bak'" | sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite
```

or this:

```
sqlite3 -cmd ".backup '..\database_backup\2012-11-30-16-16-28.bak'" mydatabase.sqlite < NUL
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I have another issue. When I run the command, I always get 0, as the return code, even if I provide sqlite.exe with the wrong parameters. For example, if I intentionally change the name of the database to mydatabase2.sqlite (which does not exist), I do not get any error, and the return code is still 0! I would appreciate if you give me a hint on this.

Comment: sqlite3 will just create a new database file if you give it a name that doesn't already exist.  You need to issue a SQL command that will fail in that case.  Example: `sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite "select * from someTableThatShouldExist where 0=1; .backup 'backupfilename'"`

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html), I'd try:

```
echo .backup '..\database_backup\2012-11-30-16-16-28.bak' | sqlite3.exe mydatabase.sqlite
```

This may also work:

```
sqlite3.exe mydatabase.sqlite ".backup '..\database_backup\2012-11-30-16-16-28.bak'"
```